# AngularJS: HTML partials ng-if not updating when $scope.loggedInUser is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

I am new to the AngularJS community and was hoping someone could help me with the following issue.

I have created a light CMS system based on an incomplete tutorial and have filled in some of the pieces myself, but i cannot get the HTML partials to update when the $scope changes;

HTML partial (admin-login.html)

```
<div ng-if="loggedInUser">
Welcome {{loggedInUser}} |  <a href="admin/pages">My Admin</a> | <a href="admin/logout">Logout</a>
</div>
```

my directive (directives.js)

```
directive('adminLogin', [
  function() {
    return {
      controller: function($scope, $cookies) {
        var user = $cookies.get('loggedInUser', {path: "/"});
        $scope.loggedInUser = user;
      },
      templateUrl: 'partials/directives/admin-login.html'
    };
  }
])
```

my controller (controllers.js)

```
controller('AdminLoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$cookies', 'AuthService','$log','flashMessageService',
    function($scope, $location, $cookies, AuthService, $log, flashMessageService) {
      $scope.credentials = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      };
      $scope.login = function(credentials) {
        AuthService.login(credentials).then(
          function(res, err) {
            $cookies.put('loggedInUser', res.data);
            $location.path('/admin/pages');
          },
          function(err) {
            flashMessageService.setMessage(err.data);

            $log.log(err);
          });
        };
    }
])
```

The scope updates but i have to refresh the page to show or hide the admin-login.html.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.loggedInUser` won't be updated once you update cookie, you should watch for cookie change in directive and update `$scope` manually.

```
directive('adminLogin', [
  function() {
    return {
      controller: function($scope, $cookies) {
        $scope.$watch(function () {
          return $cookies.get('loggedInUser', {path: "/"});
        }, function (value) {
          $scope.loggedInUser = value;
        });
      },
      templateUrl: 'partials/directives/admin-login.html'
    };
  }
])
```

Comment: thank you so much, so simple when you know how - thank you again

Comment: Yes, angular is pretty complex when you start learning, keep going and you'll see how enjoyable it is!